# How to store double variable in a checkbox?

Tags: c#

I want to pass data from Tag control to a textbox. Tag control is located in a checkbox. So if checkbox is checked, I click button and data from Tag should pass to a textbox. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I2wc.jpg

Data in Tag control is decimal number: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBUcZ.jpg

Before I did it with Int, so i used `Convert.ToInt32` and that worked properly,  but now I need convert it to double. It doesn't work and I have no idea why.

OK, I solved it. It was "culture problems". Thanks for help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us what code you used, or what happened. My *guess* is that you just used `Convert.ToDouble`, and that you're in a culture where the decimal point isn't a period, and you saw an exception. But you should fill all of this in the question, and please provide text *as text* in the question, rather than via screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You may have culture problems. So you can try with:

```
XmlConvert.ToDouble(chkBox.Tag);
```

By culture problems, I mean using 1.1 or 1,1

Hope it works.

**EDIT 1:**

Then to go backwards you need:

```
doubleValue.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```